# how to set maximum width for header or for body content other than giving width 100%

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I want to set the maximum width for body or for header without using `width:100%` how to achieve the maximum width for any body content.

Normally when I print the content in wicked-pdf the header width is not matching with the body width if I give the `width: 104%` then it is matching with body.

Even if I specify `width:100%` for header is not working properly it is not occupying full width in pdf report even default is also 100% but it is working fine with `width:104%` what is the reason for this and more over the problem is font size will become condensed or become small if we specify the width more than 100% I don't want that to happen so can any one help me!

[observe the header table and bellow lines width is not matching. after lines margin is applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOjwn.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try replace the 100% to this:

```
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you in on of your parent tags there must be some sort of padding or margin that limits the size so that it is not 100% of the page.

If your document is set pixel width you can use:

```
max-width:120px;
```

Base on your information it sounds like there is a parent style that is messing with the width, if you dont want the width to be smaller than the page you can use the alternative value:

```
min-width:120px;
```

But I suggest looking at the other tags and their styles.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this css property

```
max-width: 100%;
```